# Apache redirects port with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, apache2

Whenever I use my nginx proxy which is hosted on the same server as my apache2 server it will redirect straight to the apache2 port instead of staying on the nginx. I've tried setting the host variable to $host:apacheport and it didn't help. Can anyone help me fix this?
(Ex domain.com redirects to domain.com:1234)

Comment: Have the same issue... any luck?